# Hyperboloid of two sheets in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a hyperboloid in two sheets using Mathematica. I tried solving for z when x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 - z^2/c^2 = 1 and then using that equation for my f1 and f2, but the graph just ends up being blank.

'''f1 = (c*sqrt[-a^2b^2+x^2b^2+y^2a^2])/(ab)

f2 = (c*sqrt[-a^2b^2+x^2b^2+y^2a^2])/(ab)

Manipulate[Plot3D[{f1, f2}, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}], {a, -100, 100}, {b, -100, 100}, {c, -100, 100}]'''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are case-sensitive in Mathematica.  Therefore, `sqrt[]` is not recognized; it must be `Sqrt[]` to invoke the built-in square root function.

Multiplication of terms requires either the usage of the infix operator `*` or the use of a space   between the terms, so the product $ab$ is written as `a * b` or `a b`.

In a more general vein, it is not necessary to plot the sheets separately via `Plot3D`.  An alternative approach is to use `ContourPlot3D` as follows:

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot3D[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 - z^2/c^2 == -1, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, 100}], {a, -100, 100}, {b, -100, 100}, {c, -100, 100}]
```

It is also worth noting that the hyperboloid has one sheet for your particular equation $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1.$$  It will have two sheets if the RHS is $-1$:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} = -1.$$

You can observe this by solving for $z$ in each.  In the first case,
$$z = \pm c^2 \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} - 1}.$$  This would suggest that the surface does not contain any points inside the elliptical cylinder $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} < 1,$$ and implies that this cannot be a hyperboloid of two sheets.  In the second case, $$z = \pm c^2 \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + 1},$$ which by virtue of the fact that the square of a real number is never negative, shows that $z$ is always defined for any $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$, thus there are two distinct surfaces depending on the choice of sign.